# Why Am I Unable To Remove This Label (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, label, destroy

I am just messing around and testing things in python. For one part of my proof of concept code for a bigger project I need to create and then remove labels.
Unfortunately after I create the label and then try to remove it I get this error when I try to `.destory()` the labels:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'`

I have heard that you can get this error if your label has nothing in it and so it is "None" but mine has text. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("amazing")

def one():
    label1 = Label(root, text="one", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple").pack()
    time.sleep(2)
    label1.destroy()

def two():
    label2 = Label(root, text="two", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple").pack()
    time.sleep(2)
    label2.destroy()

def doit():
    rchoice = [two, one]
    selected = random.choice(rchoice)
    return selected()

Button = Button(root, text="Button", width=15, height=3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), fg="blue", bg="lightgreen", command=doit).pack(pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1. If you try to print the value of the labels, you will realize that it is actually `None`. That's because you have used the `pack()` method just after you have defined the widget and `pack()` returns None. So, you need to separate them.
2. Refrain from using `sleep()` in tkinter. It will freeze your mainloop. The way to do it is to use `after()`.

Here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("amazing")

def one():
    label1 = Label(root, text="one", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple")
    label1.pack()
    label1.after(2000, label1.destroy)

def two():
    label2 = Label(root, text="two", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple")
    label2.pack()
    label2.after(2000, label2.destroy)

def doit():
    rchoice = [two, one]
    selected = random.choice(rchoice)
    return selected()

Button(root, text="Button", width=15, height=3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), fg="blue", bg="lightgreen", command=doit).pack(pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```